# Protecting method calls in Spring multiactionController using methodNameResolver

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-security-acl

I am using Spring 3 and implemented MVC using simpleUrlMapping. I am having `CustomerController` class. In `CustomerController` I am having three methods:

1. View customer
2. Add customer
3. Delete customer

The above actions are getting called using method name resolver.

My requirement over here depending upon the logged in user and privilege I want to protect the corresponding method calls.

Delete customer method should be called by the privilege user and not by all the user.

I am using Spring Security as well. Is there any way to protect the delete customer method with Spring security?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

options:

```
@RequestMapping
 public void deleteCustomer(HttpServletRequest request) {
    if(request.isUserInRole("ROLE_ADMIN"){
      // do deletion
    };

 }
```

or use  **@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity**

```
 @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")
 @RequestMapping
 public void deleteCustomer(HttpServletRequest request) {
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for the answer. In spring security 3 we have @preauthorize but do you how we can achieve the same in spring security 2. Unfortunately i m using spring security 2 along with spring 3